# Can't reboot Azure App Service worker instance

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am trying to reboot the worker of an app service. I have found the worker name using this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-instance-identifiers

and called post according to this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/app-service-plans/reboot-worker

Looking at the web server farm. I can see that I've had one success 47 mins ago.

[image]

However, each subsequent request fails with the reason:

"Cannot modify this web hosting plan because another operation is in progress. Conflicting operation details: Another reboot operation is still in progress for server farm with id 'webfarmxxxx'. Procedure: runtime.workers_requestWorkerReboot_v197"

What am I missing here? Given the original request has succeeded, why can't I restart the worker again?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known problem: https://kloudexpress.wordpress.com/2020/08/01/reboot-multiple-worker-instance-app-service-plan/ and the workaround is just to wait an hour before trying again.